# Do I have a memory leak, an inaccurate memory profiler or both?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, profiler

I have implemented a linked list. To test this list for memory leaks i have also written a test case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    struct node* NextNode;
    struct node* PreviousNode;
    void* Data;
} Node;

typedef struct list
{
    Node* Head;
    Node* Last;
    int Length;
} List;

void NodeFree(Node* node)
{
    free(node);
}

void TestSuite(char* testName, bool(*testCaseDelegate)())
{
    printf("Test: %s\n", testName);
    bool result = testCaseDelegate();
    if (result)
    {
        printf("Test: passed!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Test: failed!\n");
    }
}
void ListAdd(List* list, Node* node)
{
    if (list->Head == NULL)
    {
        list->Head = node;
        list->Last = node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->Last->NextNode = node;
        list->Last = node;
    }

    list->Length++;
}

List* ListNew()
{
    List* list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->Head = NULL;
    list->Last = NULL;
    list->Length = 0;
    return list;
}

Node* NodeNew(Node* prevNode, void* data)
{
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->NextNode = NULL;
    node->PreviousNode = prevNode;
    node->Data = data;

    if (prevNode)
    {
        prevNode->NextNode = node;
    }

    return node;
}

void ListFree(List* list)
{
    Node* actual = list->Head;
    Node* next;
    while (actual)
    {
        next = actual->NextNode;
        NodeFree(actual);
        actual = next;
    }

    free(list);
}


bool ListTestAllocation()
{
    const int testRuns = 20;
    const int testNumber = 10000000;
    int testRunCount = 0;
    for (testRunCount; testRunCount != testRuns; testRunCount++)
    {
        List* list = ListNew();
        int counter = 0;
        for (counter; counter != testNumber; counter++)
        {
            ListAdd(list, NodeNew(list->Last, (void*)counter));
        }

        ListFree(list);
    }

    return false;
}

void ListTest()
{
    TestSuite("List Allocation", ListTestAllocation);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    ListTest();
}
```

I have looked up the memory usage with the Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise **Diagnostic Tool**. The Visual of this is the follwing image:

[image: Diagnostic tool output]

I am bit confused about the graph, because sometimes it hits the *zero* line (obviously it is not exactly zero but very close to it), but sometimes there seems to be a huge *memory leak* of `> 100 MB`. At the end of the test the `> 100 MB` memory leak still exists..

Can you explain me why i have sometimes the leak in the graph and sometimes not?

I **do not want you to find my memory leak** but a explaination why the graph does not fit would be great.

The fact that the top of the pyramids are flat confuses me too. Is the profiler inaccurate?

Comment: It is painful to read 100 of lines of code!

Comment: As far as I can see, your code does not actually leak anything. _Instead it might be the "usual" operating system optimization that keeps previously allocated memory mapped to the process, in case it's needed again. If the system runs low on memory or another process needs those memory pages, then the OS will unmap the pages from your process.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that could be a reason, but why would my OS swap memory when i have more than 4 GB free?

Comment: I changed the loop count from 10,000,000 to 10,000 and 100,000 and both times [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) gave a clean bill of health.  It ran for a long time (over 5 minutes) at the 10,000,000 scale and I got bored waiting.  Learn to use `valgrind`; it makes this sort of leak detection (or absence of leaks) so much easier.  I note that your code does not check for allocation failure.  However, if allocation failed, your code would almost certainly crash dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok! Thanks for checking and your time. I will look for `valgrind` soon. Thats a very good tip.